# json not outputting

Tags: php, json

I'm running this code in php

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
   $arr = array("joke" => $row['joke'], "date" => $row['date'], "rating" => $row['rating']);    
   echo json_encode($arr);

}
```

but there's no output. I am running php 5.3.6

Comment: We're going to need more information to help you; that code, by itself (if you define `$row` something appropriate), should work.

Comment: I thought its obvs...made the change.

Comment: SQL query returns nothing. And besides, you cannot output multiple JSON snippets in a loop. That will end up being an invalid serialization.

Comment: I wasn't questioning what `$row` was; I guessed that. I was just saying we need more context; for example, if there's an `ob_start` somewhere or something similar that could be blocking output. What @mario said could also be relevant.

Comment: how should this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nvm I figured it out. the way to do this is to use sql2json

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your query's failing. Either due to syntax errors or just not matching anything. Redo your code so it looks something like this:

```
$sql = "...";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

$data = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $data[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

The `or die` portion will handle the case when the query's bad and causes an error. setting $data to an empty array initially ensures that you'll get SOMETHING out of json_encode, even if it's just an empty javascript array. And then the while loop sucks the query results and stuffs into the $data array.